# Ошибка IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, kotlin

При запуске приложения выходит ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.easyjobs, PID: 5713
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<java.util.List<com.example.easyjobs.network.model.admodel.AdWorkerModel>>
    for method ApiService.getAds
    at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:116)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:67)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy3.getAds(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.easyjobs.viewModels.SignInViewModel.<init>(SignInViewModel.kt:17)
    at com.example.easyjobs.DaggerMainApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerMainApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:446)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$1.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:101)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:90)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:111)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
    at com.example.easyjobs.fragments.AdsFragment.getViewModel(AdsFragment.kt:21)
    at com.example.easyjobs.fragments.AdsFragment.observe(AdsFragment.kt:48)
    at com.example.easyjobs.fragments.AdsFragment.onViewCreated(AdsFragment.kt:42)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2895)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1543)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8330)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3670)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<java.util.List<com.example.easyjobs.network.model.admodel.AdWorkerModel>>.
      Tried:
       * retrofit2.CompletableFutureCallAdapterFactory
       * retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:272)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
        at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:114)
            ... 50 more
```

.

```
import com.example.easyjobs.network.model.admodel.AdWorkerModel
        import com.example.easyjobs.network.model.modeluser.Content
        import retrofit2.http.*  
    
  
interface ApiService {
    @Headers("myappkey")
    @GET("superjob/api/vacancy")
     fun getAds(): Flow<List<AdWorkerModel>>
}
```

.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import com.example.easyjobs.network.ApiService
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject

    @HiltViewModel
    class SignInViewModel @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService) : ViewModel() {
    val allNotes: LiveData<List<AdWorkerModel>> = apiService.getAds().asLiveData()  }
```

.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager

import com.example.easyjobs.R
import com.example.easyjobs.Splash.activities.MainContentActivity
import com.example.easyjobs.adapters.AdsAdapter
import com.example.easyjobs.databinding.FragmentAdsBinding
import com.example.easyjobs.viewModels.SignInViewModel

class AdsFragment : Fragment() {
    private var binding: FragmentAdsBinding? = null
    private lateinit var adapter:AdsAdapter
    private val viewModel: SignInViewModel by activityViewModels ()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentAdsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        binding?.btnAdd?.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as MainContentActivity).navController.navigate(R.id.action_adsFragment_to_createAdsFragment)
        }
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initRc()
        observe()


    }

    private fun observe(){
        viewModel.allNotes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }
    }

    private fun initRc()=with(binding){
        this?.rcView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        adapter = AdsAdapter()
        this?.rcView?.adapter = adapter
    }
}







 @Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    ///
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit():ApiService=
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(provide())
            .build()
            .create(ApiService::class.java)
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provide():OkHttpClient{
        val interceptor= HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level=HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

      return OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает suspend для функций getAds.

сначала я бы удалил Flow из метода API ->

```
interface ApiService {
    @Headers("myappkey")
    @GET("superjob/api/vacancy")
    suspend fun getAds(): List<AdWorkerModel>
}
```

после добавления suspend должен обновить свою модель просмотра следующим образом ->

```
@HiltViewModel
class SignInViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: ApiService
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _allNotes = MutableLiveData<List<AdWorkerModel>>()
    val allNotes: LiveData<List<AdWorkerModel>> = _allNotes

    init{
       viewModelScope.launch {
          val adds = apiService.getAds()
          _allNotes.value = adds
    }
}
```

Comment: теперь показывает :
Suspend function 'getAds' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

в val allNotes: LiveData<List<AdWorkerModel>> = apiService.getAds().asLiveData()

Comment: @Kufeldradion updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что Retrofit из коробки не понимает что вы хотите от него вернуть. Нет соответствующей фабрики. Чтобы на выходе был Flow нужно

1. Добавить фабрику вызова Flow в объект ретрофит. Например [Фабрика Retrofit-Call-Flow-Factory](https://github.com/MohammadSianaki/Retrofit2-Flow-Call-Adapter). В таком случае нужно будет в билдере Retrofit добавить строчку `.addCallAdapterFactory(FlowCallAdapterFactory.create())`
2. Можно добавить адаптер, идущий вместе с Retrofit [Rx-Java2-adapter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2) добавив при этом в билдер Retrofit `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())`, выходным типом сделать `Observable<List<AdWorkerModel>>` сделать переход из Observable вo Flow уже вне запроса. Например - в репозитории. Для перехода на Flow используется функуция из пакета [Kotlin-coroutines-rx2](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/) `.asFlow()`